# ASP.NET returning 403 without calling the application code

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am running an ASP.NET service under IIS on my dev box (Windows 10).  I am posting to a localhost URL and I get a 403 back.  Nothing too strange there.

However, when I attach to the app pool process and set a breakpoint (or look at my logs) there is no evidence that the service ever got called.  I see logging done when the service initializes but nothing when the call happens.

I stopped the relevant application pool (which is **v4.0, Integrated**) and tried again.  I got the expected 503 back so I know I have the right app pool but I am at a loss to find out what part of IIS (because it is not in *my* code) is returning a 403.  I tried turning on Failed Request Logging for 403 which generated some output for the call but the logging provided no significant information.

How does one troubleshoot such a circumstance?

P.S.  This code has worked fine before.  I have debugged it many times w/o problems on the same machine.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: It sounds just like your application didn't choose the right handler to handle your request. What handler returned 403 error? So please check the sub-status code of 403 error and  ensure your IIS asp.net and asp.net extensionsibility has been installed.

Comment: My code implements IHttpModule.  It is an IIS module itself.  It has to be installed in the GAC.    Running the Failed request tracing.  I see the call get to my module (it does get to my module--the module inserts itself via a web.config setting.) but on that step the status is "HANDLER_CHANGED".   The vast majority of the earlier modules get the trace status "MODULE_PRECONDITION_NOT_MATCH".   
I do not know how to interpret "HANDLER_CHANGED".  I cannot find documentation on what that status means when found in a Failed Req Tracing file.